# Can I attack with Bigby's hand while grappling someone with Bigbys hand?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, combat, grapple, attack

Can I grapple someone with Bigbys hand, and then on the next turn attack a different target with Bigbys hand,while still grappling the first target.

Comment: Just to clarify, the summoned hand is what you want to perform each actual grappling check?

Comment: Mandatory [OoTS link](http://oots.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Uses_Various_Hand_Spells)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No

The text of Bigby's Hand is explicit (***emphasis mine***):

> ...
>
> When you cast the spell and as a bonus action on your subsequent turns, you can move the hand up to 60 feet and then cause ***one*** of the following effects with it.
>
> ...

It doesn't say that you can maintain any previous ones, just that you can cause one of the effects. So the interpretation here should be that if you choose a different effect then any previous effect ends when the new effect starts.

So if you use Bigby's Grasping Hand one turn, and then use Bigby's Clenched Fist on a subsequent turn, the Grapple from the Grasping Hand is released when the Clenched Fist is attempted.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, as long as the hand doesn't move.

There is no action involved in maintaining a grapple, so it would be free to otherwise act on subsequent turns. However, if the wizard moved the hand away from the grappled creature the grapple would end.

From the Grappled Condition:

> The condition also ends if an effect removes the grappled creature from the reach of the grappler or grappling effect.

The spell states that the Caster moves the hand, the hand doesn't move on its own, so moving the hand would end the grapple.

Comment: Why wouldn't the creature move with the hand if they're still grappled@